# How to get row counts from a table by different conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table named "**posts**" with fields **id,post,status** etc..
I want to create a query to get post count by the post's status like this

```
------------------------------
| published | draft  | trash | 
------------------------------
| 150       |  15    |  0    |
------------------------------
```

Please help me :

Comment: SELECT SUM(main_a.published), SUM(main_a.draft), SUM(main_a.trash) FROM (SELECT IF (status= 'published' ,COUNT(), 0 ) AS published, IF (status= 'draft' , COUNT() , 0) AS draft, IF (status= 'trash', COUNT(*) , 0) AS trash FROM posts GROUP BY status ) main_a

Comment: @DeepakKumar, IMHO that looks like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Yes I have posted it in answer, but you have not mind that's why I commented, It is perfect answer as you want result in above display. Can you accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) count FROM posts GROUP BY status
```

That is more typical, and will give you the following.

```
-----------------------
| status    | count   | 
-----------------------
| published |  150    |
-----------------------
| draft     |  15     |
-----------------------
| trash     |  0      |
-----------------------
```

If you want *exactly* the table you asked for, do

```
SELECT SUM(CASE status WHEN 'published' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) published,
    SUM(CASE status WHEN 'draft' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) draft,
    SUM(CASE status WHEN 'trash' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) trash
FROM posts
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   status, COUNT(*)
FROM     posts
GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT published , COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE`published `= 150;`

OR

`SELECT published , COUNT(*) FROM posts;`

Answer (score 0):

The perfect solution, As you display :

**

```
SELECT SUM(main_a.published) as published, SUM(main_a.draft) as draft, SUM(main_a.trash) as trash FROM (SELECT 
      IF (`status`= 'published' ,COUNT(*), 0 ) AS published, 
      IF (`status`= 'draft' , COUNT(*) , 0) AS draft,
      IF (`status`= 'trash', COUNT(*) , 0) AS trash  FROM posts GROUP BY `status` ) main_a
```

**

**Note your table structure should as follows :**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post` text,
  `status` enum('published','draft','trash') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(main_a.published) as published, SUM(main_a.draft) as draft, SUM(main_a.trash) as trash FROM (SELECT IF (status= 'published' ,COUNT(), 0 ) AS published, IF (status= 'draft' , COUNT() , 0) AS draft, IF (status= 'trash', COUNT(*) , 0) AS trash FROM posts GROUP BY status ) main_a
```